# Customize local login page of EditProfile policy in Azure Active Directory B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Is there a way, to customize the login page for the custom login when executing the edit profile policy? After starting the edit profile police (e.g. with run now), i get the ip selection. Then i click on local account and get the default ui.

I'm currently using the default policy and not the identity experience framework.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way, to customize the login page for the custom login when executing the edit profile policy?

Yes, we could get the details steps from the this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization-helper-tool). Following is the snippet from the tutorial.

> To customize the look and feel of your policy, you need to first **create HTML and CSS files** using the specific conventions of Azure AD B2C. You can then upload your static content to a publicly available location so that Azure AD B2C can access it. This could be your own dedicated web server, Azure Blob Storage, Azure Content Delivery Network, or any other static resource-hosting provider. The only requirements are that your content is available over HTTPS and can be accessed by using CORS.

---

**Detail steps:**

> - Sign in to your tenant on the Azure portal and navigate to the B2C features blade.
>     Click Sign-up or sign-in policies, click your policy and click on Edit (for example, "b2c_1_sign_up_sign_in").
> - Click Page UI customization and then Unified sign-up or sign-in page.
>     Toggle the Use custom page switch to Yes. In the Custom page URI field, enter https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/b2c/wingtip/unified.html. Click OK.
>     -Click Local account sign-up page. Toggle the Use custom template switch to Yes. In the Custom page URI field, enter https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/b2c/wingtip/selfasserted.html.
> - Repeat the same step for the Social account sign-up page. Click OK twice to close the UI customization blades.
> - Click Save.

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you for you replay, but it does not cover my question. I have already customized the UI, but if I use an profile edit policy, I only can customize the idp, profile edit and custom error page. The local login page is not available. Any ideas how to customize it?